# Loop through document on load to find element ID

Tags: jquery, loops, dynamic, foreach

I have an element that is loaded into the page dynamically and unfortunately I cannot control where the app puts the `<div>` element and it takes a few seconds to load in. What is the appropriate way to loop through the document until `<div id="chatra">` is found and then stop the loop and append it to another `<div>`.

Thanks

Comment: You put the tag jquery in there, that implies you want to do this w/ jQuery, is that correct??  If so, you answer is: $('#id_of_div_you_want_to_insert_into').append($('#chatra').html());

Comment: Hello @Severun, Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately I have tried that before and did again just then and it did not work. For some reason the <div id="chatra"> remains in the body tag.

Comment: You want to also delete the original element? then do something like: var chatra_elem = $('#chatra'); chatra_html = $('#chatra').html(); chatra_elem.remove();$('#id_of_div_you_want_to_insert_into').append(chatra_html);

Comment: If the above is not working, then I would look for more than one element that has id="chatra"...an ID needs to be unique.

Comment: The above should be var chatra_elem = $('#chatra'); chatra_html = chatra_elem.html();  /* That's so you don't look up the ID="chatra" twice */

Comment: I really do appreciate all the replies. I understand the logic you used and thought that myself but for some reason the darn thing is not being appended. I watched the inspector and the <div id="chatra"> does not come into the dom until like 5 seconds.

Comment: Ah gotcha, then if you don't have more than one occurrence of <div id="chatra"> then I suspect that <div id="chatra"> is being programatically added to the DOM?  If that's the case, then you are probably hitting the code to look for <div id="chatra"> before it's been added to the DOM.  A hack around for that is to add your code inside of a settimeout function, like setTimeout(function(){ /* The code above that looks for chatra */ }, 0);  This will cause the code that looks for chatra to wait for the next go-around of the event loop so it _SHOULD_ be drawn into the DOM by the time it fires.

Comment: That did work and I had to wrap it in a <div> tag with the id "chatra" as that did not pull over. Unfortunately it seems that moving it only loads some of the styles but does not initiate the widget again. I'll have to find another solution to my problem. Basically I need to stop a fixed item from scrolling when it hits the bottom of a page wrapper. But the <div id="chatra" is out of the element I need to calculate the offsets.

Comment: Well sounds like you're trying to accomplish more than just deleting an element from a div and placing it elsewhere.  Perhaps if you write a complete description with some screenshots/code examples, we could provide a bit more help.  I think your solution may be more of a CSS issue than a Javascript issue, and solving it in the DOM may not be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can simply loop through all div's when document is ready e.g. :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each($('div'), function(i,v){
    if ($(v).attr('id') == 'myid') {
        console.log('Found you element', $(v))
    }
  })
 });
```

You can modify according to your requirements. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: the same as $('#myid), but less efficient.  Also document.ready will fire when the document is loaded, but before any elements are programatically added, later via Javascript, the setTimeout, helps w/ that.